# Using Apple's coding examples in XCode 4.3.2 - Base SDK Missing

Tags: xcode, sdk

I'm discovering XCode and iOS development.
Delving into the iOS documentation, I've tried to download and run some of the programming examples.
As an example, I'll use AccelerometerGraph.
If I download the code and try to compile, i get an error message, and I realize that the Navigation panel tells me : Base SDK Missing. 
After fiddling around (the existing answers on stackoverflow refer to the Xcode 3.2 answer, which doesn't work) I figured I should go to "Editor > Validate Settings…" and accept the changes. 
It "seems" to work, (as in the "Missing SDK" message disappears, and I can compile) but I'm wondering if i'm missing something more fundamental.
Also, I thought if there is such a fundamental change, it would be useful to have it up there in one of the questions.

Thx
P.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the project settings and choose "Latest SDK" for the SDK option and that should fix your projects.

[image: how to change Base SDK in projects]

And if you want to be super helpful, file a bug with Apple (at http://bugreporter.apple.com) and tell them to update these outdated sample projects to use the latest SDK's if possible.

Comment: And yes, if the automatic process you used doesn't work, on another sample, you can go to the project settings as indicated.  Note that the blue project icon is selected in the left column.

Answer (score 0):

Not missing something more fundamental.  Apple's sample projects have a variety of vintages.  Mostly they compile and link under the current versions of Xcode and friends.  Some need to be brought up to date.  What you found was one that was originally set up for an obsolete version of the SDK and it compiles and links fine with one that was automagically found on your system when you updated it.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply.